# How to create a virtual environment in Ubuntu 20.04 of python 2.7?

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu, virtualenv, python-venv

I was able to make the virtual environment of `python3` but not able to make of `python2`.

```
which python2
/usr/bin/python2
python2 -V
Python 2.7.18
```

Answer (score 0):

```
virtualenv --python=$(which python2) $path_of_new_venv_directory
```